# Text is hidden on mobile breadcrumb layout

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

Why don't some of the list items (`li`) look like arrows when I test it on a mobile viewport? It seems that some of the text disappears as well, possibly behind the arrow-triangles.

[image]

```css
.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  color: white !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 35px;
  background: brown;
  /* fallback color */
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb a,
.breadcrumb a:link,
.breadcrumb a:visited,
.breadcrumb a:active {
  color: #212121;
}

.breadcrumb li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent !important;
  border-left: 30px solid hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1) !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  margin-top: -50px !important;
  left: 100% !important;
  z-index: 2 !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(8) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 15%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(8):after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 15%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(7) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(7):after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(6) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(6):after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 45%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5):after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 45%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 55%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4):after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 55%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 65%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3):after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 65%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 75%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2):after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 75%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(1) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 85%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(1):after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 85%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  color: white
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1);
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:hover {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1);
}

.breadcrumb li:hover:after {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important;
}

.border {
  width: 100%
}

.shadow:after {
  border-left-color: #54AF4A !important;
}

li .shadow {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #b3b2b2 !important;
}

.border a {
  color: blue;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .breadcrumb {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .breadcrumb li {
    font-size: 4px !important;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 35px;
  }
  .breadcrumb li {
    padding-left: 1px !important;
    padding-right: 1px !important;
  }
  .breadcrumb img {
    height: 6px !important;
    width: auto !important;
  }
  .breadcrumb a,
  .breadcrumb a:link,
  .breadcrumb a:visited,
  .breadcrumb a:active {
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 4px !important;
  }
  .breadcrumb li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="">CONCEPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="">POUR/MOUNT</a></li>
  <li><a href="">TEETH SET UP</a></li>
  <li><a href="">FINALIZATION</a></li>
  <li><a href="">SHIPPED</a></li>
  <li><a href="">CONVERSION</a></li>
  </u>
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be large triangles at the end of the arrows? If I remove the style tags from your CSS, the arrows look like they do on mobile.

Comment: @RaheelJunaid can you add answer with codesnippit to see if it look arrows in the mobile?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you think an arrow looks like. The current snippet you have attached shows arrows with really tall ends, and on mobile, they look like regular breadcrumb arrows.

Comment: @RaheelJunaid but you cant see the font

Comment: @RaheelJunaid i added a picture of how it looks from mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple breadcrumb layout that is also mobile responsive.

### A few problems in your code

- The media query duplicated a lot of the properties which was unnecessary
- The beginning and ending `<style>` tags were being treated as selectors
- The `!important` values served no purpose in this code example so they were removed
- Your ending `</ul>` tag was `</u>` which may have hindered functionality
- You don't need to use `overflow: hidden;` (I'll demonstrate why)
- 4px font is almost unseeable on mobile

### The changes I made

- I used flexbox to align the breadcrumbs horizontally
- I used flexbox to align the link containers and the triangles horizontally
- Instead of using the `:after` selector for the list elements, I used `:before` as it made it more responsive and aligned with your original `left: 100%` property
- I changed `position: absolute` to `position: relative` for responsiveness.
- I aligned the links vertically using `align-items: center;`

You may then change the height and width using the border sizes (if you prefer a smaller breadcrumb layout for mobile).

```css
.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  color: white !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: brown;
  /* fallback color */
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.breadcrumb a,
.breadcrumb a:link,
.breadcrumb a:visited,
.breadcrumb a:active {
  color: #212121;
  margin: 0 10px;
}


.breadcrumb li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1);
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(8) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 15%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(8):before {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 15%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(7) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(7):before {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(6) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(6):before {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 45%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5):before {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 45%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 55%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4):before {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 55%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 65%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3):before {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 65%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 75%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2):before {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 75%, 1) !important;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(1) {
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 85%, 1) !important;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(1):before {
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 85%, 1) !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="">CONCEPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="">POUR/MOUNT</a></li>
  <li><a href="">TEETH SET UP</a></li>
  <li><a href="">FINALIZATION</a></li>
  <li><a href="">SHIPPED</a></li>
  <li><a href="">CONVERSION</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you :) but on phone the first li left padding is much bigger from the rest. How can i make them all equal?

Comment: I edit my question from hello to different writing. it looks perfect on big screen but in the small screen it looks weird.

Comment: I added some margin left to the first child using li:nth-child(1). Otherwise all of them have equal margin (10px)

Comment: Can you please change hello to what i add in my question please

Comment: I’ve changed it, is that better?

Comment: Yes thank you, but check how teeth setup is squeezed. Can you fix that?

Comment: Are you referring to how the triangles look squished vertically? If so, you could modify the border properties to fit your desired result, just make sure they’re equal.

Comment: No it looks good! I will accept your answer. can you just fix the padding from top and bottom to be the same heigh of the arrow?

Comment: Any customizations you would like to make can be done on your project. The answer is just to provide an answer to your problem. I hope I have done that sufficiently.

Comment: @nourza: this site is for general Q&A. Please don't use it as a platform for free work! If you have a supplementary question that arises after a helpful answer, it is ideal if you give that a genuine go yourself. If you are still stuck, then ask a new question. Good luck!